# Adding access to PPP

Tags: embedded, route, ppp

I have a PPP connection over USB (dev ppp0), and an eth0 connection. My Linux box has IP 192.168.1.1, I have a second Windows PC with an IP of 192.168.1.3. The ppp conection is 192.168.1.2 - which is a correctly configured embedded system. I would like traffic to be able to flow between the ppp0 connection, and 192.168.1.3. When I try and ping 192.168.1.2 from 192.168.1.3 I find that the destination is unreachable - I actually get that specific message. I can ping 192.168.2 from 192.168.1.1. I can also ping 192.168.1.3 from 192.168.1.1 and visa verse.  I have turned on IP Forwarding. I have also executed the following commands.

```
route add -net 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 gw 192.168.1.1
route add -net 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev ppp0
```

I would like network traffic destined for 192.168.1.2 to be routed to/from whatever other host is on the same 192.168.1.* network. How do I do this.

Comment: Please post the output of `ifconfig`, `route -n`, and `iptables -nvL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.1.2/255.255.255.0  -j DNAT --to 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0
```